# Is there a way to replace all colum values with a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code:

```
l_names = [ ]
for l in links:
   l_names.append(l.get_text())


df = [ ]
for u in urls:
    req = s.get(u)
    req_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')
    req_tables = req_soup.find_all('table', {'class':'infobox vevent'})
    req_df = pd.read_html(str(req_tables), flavor='bs4', header=0)
    dfr = pd.concat(req_df)
    dfr = dfr.drop(index=0)
    dfr.columns = range(dfr.columns.size)
    dfr[1] = dfr[1].str.replace(r"([A-Z])", r" \1").str.strip().str.replace(' ', ' ')
    dfr = dfr[~dfr[0].isin(remove_list)]
    dfr = dfr.dropna()
    dfr = dfr.reset_index(drop=True)
    dfr.insert(loc=0, column='Title', value='Change')
    df.append(dfr)
```

Here is some info about `l_names` and `df`:

```
len(l_names)
83

len(df)
83

display(df)


 [    Title                 0                               1
 0  Change             Genre               Melodrama Revenge
 1  Change        Written by  Kwon  Soon-won Park  Sang-wook
 2  Change       Directed by                  Yoon  Sung-sik
 3  Change          Starring      Park  Si-hoo Jang  Hee-jin
 4  Change   No. of episodes                              16
 5  Change      Running time                      60 minutes
 6  Change  Original network                     T V  Chosun
 7  Change  Original release     January 27 – March 24, 2019,
     Title                 0                                               1
 0  Change             Genre                                  Romance Comedy
 1  Change        Written by                   Jung  Do-yoon  Oh  Seon-hyung
 2  Change       Directed by                      Lee  Jin-seo  Lee  So-yeon
 3  Change          Starring  Jang  Na-ra Choi  Daniel Ryu  Jin Kim  Min-seo
 4  Change   No. of episodes                                              20
 5  Change      Running time         Mondays and  Tuesdays at 21:55 ( K S T)
 6  Change  Original network                    Korean  Broadcasting  System
 7  Change  Original release                            2  May –5  July 2011,
     Title                 0                                                  1
 0  Change             Genre                          Mystery Thriller Suspense
 1  Change       Directed by                                      Kim  Yong-soo
 2  Change          Starring  Cho  Yeo-jeong  Kim  Min-jun  Shin  Yoon-joo  ...
 3  Change   No. of episodes                                                  4
 4  Change      Running time                                      61-65 minutes
 5  Change  Original network                                             K B S2
 6  Change  Original release                          March 14 – March 22, 2016,
     Title                 0                                                  1
 0  Change             Genre                         Melodrama  Comedy  Romance
 1  Change        Written by                                     Yoon  Sung-hee
 2  Change       Directed by                                    Lee  Joon-hyung
 3  Change          Starring  Ji  Chang-wook Wang  Ji-hye Kim  Young-kwang P...
 4  Change   No. of episodes                                                 24
 5  Change      Running time        Wednesdays and  Thursdays at 21:20 ( K S T)
 6  Change  Original network                                         Channel  A
 7  Change  Original release                  December 21, 2011 – March 8, 2012,
```

I want to replace 'Change' with TV show names which are stored in `l_names`.
For this example, only four TV shows will be given but I have 83 in total.

```
print(l_names)
['Babel', 'Baby Faced Beauty', 'Babysitter', "Bachelor's Vegetable Store"]
```

But when I try to plug in `l_names` in my for loop code as my values. I get an error.

```
    dfr.insert(loc=0, column='Title', value=l_names)
    df.append(dfr)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [96], in <cell line: 19>()
     29 dfr = dfr.dropna()
     30 dfr = dfr.reset_index(drop=True)
---> 31 dfr.insert(loc=0, column='Title', value=l_names)
     32 df.append(dfr)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/beans/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4444, in DataFrame.insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   4441 if not isinstance(loc, int):
   4442     raise TypeError("loc must be int")
-> 4444 value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   4445 self._mgr.insert(loc, column, value)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/beans/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4535, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   4532     return _reindex_for_setitem(value, self.index)
   4534 if is_list_like(value):
-> 4535     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
   4536 return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/beans/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py:557, in require_length_match(data, index)
    553 """
    554 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    555 """
    556 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 557     raise ValueError(
    558         "Length of values "
    559         f"({len(data)}) "
    560         "does not match length of index "
    561         f"({len(index)})"
    562     )

ValueError: Length of values (83) does not match length of index (8)
```

I also tried adding a for loop in my for loop.

```
    for x in l_names:
        dfr.insert(loc=0, column='Title', value=x)
        df.append(dfr)
```

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [97], in <cell line: 19>()
     30 dfr = dfr.reset_index(drop=True)
     31 for x in l_names:
---> 32     dfr.insert(loc=0, column='Title', value=x)
     33     df.append(dfr)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/beans/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4440, in DataFrame.insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   4434     raise ValueError(
   4435         "Cannot specify 'allow_duplicates=True' when "
   4436         "'self.flags.allows_duplicate_labels' is False."
   4437     )
   4438 if not allow_duplicates and column in self.columns:
   4439     # Should this be a different kind of error??
-> 4440     raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
   4441 if not isinstance(loc, int):
   4442     raise TypeError("loc must be int")

ValueError: cannot insert Title, already exists
```

I also added `allow_duplicates = True` and all that did was just make the Titles and names repeat over and over again.

I also have tried other methods to add in the title name.
But my lack of skill in using `pandas` has led me to this dead end.

Thanks again for your help and expertise.

Comment: You haven't really given enough context here. I assume you want the title of the url you scraped? If that's the case why don't you set it within the loop?

Comment: I want to CHANGE the one thats called CHANGE in my scraped dataframe. I did and all it does is  either give only one url title or just repeat the dataframe over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: After you create the `df` with 83 dataframe in it, you can loop `df` and update `Title` column values.

```
for i,dfr in enumerate(df):
    dfr['Title'] = l_names[i]
```

Solution 2: In your loop, you don't need an extra loop, just use the index `i` to get the title and insert it.

```
for i,u in enumerate(urls):
    ...
    dfr.insert(loc=0,column="Title",value=l_names[i])
    df.append(dfr)
```

Comment: You have my deepest gratitude. I would give you a plus but I need more reputation to do that. You are a life saver. Thanks again for taking the time to help me. I will add enumerate into my bag of tricks. Thanks again.